# Compiler generated sealed class for delegate keyword contains virtual methods

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, cil, il

When `delegate` keyword is used in C#, the C# compiler automatically generates a class derived from `System.MulticastDelegate` class.

This compiler generated class contains 3 methods as well: `Invoke, BeginInvoke and EndInvoke`.

All these three methods are marked `public virtual extern` but interestingly the class itself is marked `sealed`.

Virtual methods defined in a sealed class not only strikes as counter-intuitive but are actually illegal in C#.

So my question is, is there a specific reason for this or is it just one of those harmless things done keeping in mind some hypothetical future enhancement?

Edit 1:

Can the reason be to force use of 'callVirt' IL opcode as opposed to 'call' so that delegate object is always checked for null by the CLR before trying to execute any of the three methods? Though I fail to see why a `delegate` should be a special case in this respect.

Also isn't it a performance hit to force use of `callvirt` (though it may be minuscule)

Edit 2:

Added CIL tag, as it turns out that the C# way of defining delegates is in fact mandated by the CIL standard. Standard states that (following is not full text)

> Delegates shall have a base type of System.Delegate. Delegates shall
>   be declared **sealed**, and the only members a delegate shall have are
>   either the first two or all four methods as specified here. These
>   methods shall be declared runtime and managed. They shall not have a
>   body, since that body shall be created automatically by the VES. Other
>   methods available on delegates are inherited from the class
>   System.Delegate in the Base Class Library. The delegate methods are:
>
> 1. The instance constructor
> 2. The Invoke method shall be **virtual**
> 3. The BeginInvoke method, if present, shall be **virtual**
> 4. The EndInvoke method shall be **virtual**

So this is definitely not a side effect of compiler process or is similar to other interesting compiler outputs.

If standard emphasizes something, it must be for some good reason and rationale.

So the question now is why does CIL standard for delegates emphasizes on sealed and virtual at the same time?

Does the catch lie here?:

> They shall not have a body, since that body shall be created automatically by the VES.

Are they marked virtual so that the VES/CLR generated body can be executed on invocation of these methods?

Comment: Don't forget, what isn't valid in C# could be perfectly valid in IL - there are other instances of this currently, this is likely another. But +1 for the interesting find.

Comment: I tried that with ILDasm and the override keyword is translated to virtual in IL.

Comment: @MBen yes but for C# generated delegate class there are no corresponding base class methods to override. Hence virtual keyword here is not a result of 'override' :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in my question that this sealed virtual anomaly is in fact mandated by CIL standard. It remains unclear why CIL standard specifically mentions that delegate methods `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` should be virtual while at the same time mandating to seal the `Delegate` inherited class.

Also, after going through SSCLI code I learnt that internal optimization of JIT compiler automatically translates any `callvirt` call on a virtual method of a sealed class to normal call with additional null check. This means that delegates do not suffer any performance hit when its Invoke (or any of the other two) method is called through `callvirt` instruction despite being marked virtual in the IL.

When a delegate's invoke is called, CLR automatically emits a highly optimized body for this method as opposed to compiling IL code to generate body which it does for 'normal' methods. This has nothing to do with being marked `virtual` in the IL.

I have also verified by hand modifying IL code and re-assembling it that virtual can be safely removed from the generated delegate class's IL code. The generated assembly despite being in violation of the CIL standard runs perfectly fine.

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit MainApp
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .class auto ansi sealed nested private Echo
         extends [mscorlib]System.MulticastDelegate
  {
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
            instance void  .ctor(object 'object',
                                 native int 'method') runtime managed
    {
    } // end of method Echo::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig instance int32  Invoke(int32 i) runtime managed
    {
    } // end of method Echo::Invoke

    .method public hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult 
            BeginInvoke(int32 i,
                        class [mscorlib]System.AsyncCallback callback,
                        object 'object') runtime managed
    {
    } // end of method Echo::BeginInvoke

    .method public hidebysig instance int32  EndInvoke(class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult result) runtime managed
    {
    } // end of method Echo::EndInvoke

  } // end of class Echo

  .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       34 (0x22)
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init ([0] class MainApp app,
             [1] class MainApp/Echo dele)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void MainApp::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldftn      instance int32 MainApp::DoEcho(int32)
    IL_000e:  newobj     instance void MainApp/Echo::.ctor(object,
                                                           native int)
    IL_0013:  stloc.1
    IL_0014:  ldloc.1
    IL_0015:  ldc.i4.5
    //callvirt can also be replaced by call without affecting functionality
    // since delegate object is essentially not null here
    IL_0016:  callvirt   instance int32 MainApp/Echo::Invoke(int32)
    IL_001b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0020:  nop
    IL_0021:  ret
  } // end of method MainApp::Main

  .method private hidebysig instance int32 
          DoEcho(int32 i) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       7 (0x7)
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init ([0] int32 CS$1$0000)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1
    IL_0002:  stloc.0
    IL_0003:  br.s       IL_0005

    IL_0005:  ldloc.0
    IL_0006:  ret
  } // end of method MainApp::DoEcho

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // Code size       7 (0x7)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  ret
  } // end of method MainApp::.ctor

} // end of class MainApp
```

Note that I have converted the virtual methods to normal instance methods.

Since this changed IL runs perfectly fine it proves that standard mandated virtual methods in the sealed delegate class are not necessary. They can be normal instance methods as well.

So in all probability this anomaly is either to emphasize that calling these three delegate methods will in-fact result in calling of some other method (i.e. run-time polymorphism just like 'normal' virtual methods) or this has been so to accommodate some future hypothetical enhancement related to delegates.

Comment: Can you reference me to where you learned about the 'highly optimized body opposed to compiling IL'?

Answer (score 5):

You are being tripped up by the disassembler you used to look at the type definition.  Which must translate the IL back to a recognizable language, like C#.  This is not in general possible to do with full fidelity, the rules for IL are **not** the same as the C# language rules.  This doesn't just happen for delegates, an interface implementation method is virtual as well, even though you don't declare it virtual in your C# code.

To further muddy the waters, IL actually permits a compiler to emit a non-virtual call for a virtual method if it can determine the target object from code analysis.  But that will never happen for a delegate or interface call.  And IL permits making a virtual call to a non-virtual method, something the C# compiler does with gusto to implement the guarantee that an instance method can never be called with a null *this*.

But that C# usage is a clever trick, discovered only after the CLR was designed.  The original intent of *virtual* certainly was to annotate that the method should be called with Callvirt.  Ultimately it doesn't matter because the compiler is aware of delegate and interface behavior and will always emit Callvirt.  And the actual method call is implemented in CLR code which assumes a Callvirt activation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please see my edit2 to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a side-effect of the compilation process. I do not know the exact reason for this, there are more examples of this kind of behaviour. For example, a compiled static class becomes an abstract sealed class (so you can't create an instance of it, and you cannot inherit from it).

Comment: Very interesting point about Static classes :)...but I think abstract sealed is pretty much the only way semantics of Static classes can be represented in MSIL as 'you can't create an instance of it, you cannot inherit from it' along with 'the class itself does not contain any instance members' is the contract for static.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not to be specific to delegates.
I tried this example :

```
 public abstract class Base
    {
        public abstract void Test();
    }

    public sealed class Derived : Base
    {
        public override  void Test()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and in ILDasm I get this for the implementation of Test() :

```
.method public hidebysig virtual instance void 
        Test() cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.NotImplementedException::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  throw
} // end of method Derived::Test
```

Might be that the override keyword is not a CLR keyword.

Comment: Thanks for a response. This is another very interesting find but the difference with delegate is that the three methods I mention are 'newly' generated methods and not overrides. Overrides are essentially virtual and as you mentioned I also think that MSIL does not have a corresponding override keyword.

Comment: Just a point I just learned. Absence of keyword 'newslot' before virtual signifies that the virtual method is an override...