# What is captured in Expression.Compile

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Lets assume I got a class of Type Foo with a Property Bar.

And i got the following Method:

```
public static void DumpValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
     MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
     Debug.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", memberExpression.Member.Name, expr.Compile()());
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
Foo a = new Foo{Bar ="Hello"};
Foo b = new Foo{Bar ="World"};
DumpValue(() => a.Test);
DumpValue(() => b.Test);
```

Which gives the output:

```
Bar => Hello
Bar => World
```

My Question here concerns the **consecutive Compile calls**. Is it smart enough to rework the Func<T>
Into something like Func<Foo,T> (internally) so the instance is removed so it can be used for any instance of Foo and only the resulting Delegate is instancespecific? Or does it indeed Compile it **completely** for each instance?

If the latter, do i need to worry about polluting Memory with tons of compiled functions, I cannot see any impact from my tests.

I know this can be avoided by rewriting the DumpValue, but i want to know what happens behind the Scenes. This is just an example here to illustrate.

I dug my way through the [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,200) but couldnt find any clue.

**Rephrasing this Question:**
Does the Compiler optimize the instance out and caches some info here and only bakes the instance into the final delegate, or does he go "all the way all the time"?

Comment: It is compile new `DynamicMethod` for every call to `.Compile()`.

Comment: And each "compiled" `Expression` is connected to a different instance of `Foo` (`a` and `b`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Question here concerns the Compile. Is it smart enough to rework
>   the Func Into something like Func so the instance is removed
>   so it can be used for any instance of Foo ? Or does it indeed Compile
>   it for each instance?

When you compile an expression you get a *delegate*. If you want to use an arbitrary instance when you call the compiled expression, then you don't need a `Expression<Func<T>>` but `Expression<Func<T, S>>`.

Otherwise, you'll need to build an expression tree from the scratch to don't use captured references within the expression body.

### About the caching thing...

I've modified your code to check that even when you compile twice the same expression tree, you get different delegate instances:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static Delegate DumpValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expr.Body as MemberExpression;

        return expr.Compile();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string a = "foo";
        string b = "bar";

        var del1 = DumpValue(() => a);
        var del2 = DumpValue(() => b);

        // FALSE
        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(del1, del2));
    }
}
```

In short, then, there's no caching and as my answer has stated from the start, I doubt that such feature would be easy to implement, because it might be very use cases and edge cases where generalizing expressions might be a time-consuming task. **Probably in most cases many delegate instances are better than implementing a caching algorithm (and even expression tree transformations prior to get them compiled...).**

Comment: This doesnt really answer my question. I know i could rewrite the expression. I try to rephrase my Question so its more clear that i want to know if the compiler optimizes the instance out behind the scenes.

Comment: @CSharpie It indeed answers your question, but I've just added background to my answer to just not answer **no** ;) There's no optimization. Expression trees are like abstract syntax trees but in a more advanced stage of compilation. It's like building C# code during run-time without parsing. If an expression accesses a reference, it will use that reference, you can't change this.

Comment: I do bellieve you are too quick here. See this
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/StackSpiller.cs,106

Comment: @CSharpie Isn't this private/internal? :\

Comment: @CSharpie About your updated question, we should expect an Eric Lippert's answer, shouldn't we?

Comment: I give up you dont understand what i am asking, your example proves this. Im calling Compile 2 times. You dont need to explain to me how delegates work.Still thank you for the efforf here.

Comment: @CSharpie I know that you call compile twice. And what does this change your question and my answer?

Comment: @CSharpie I'm downloading LinqPad just to show you something about delegates....... :D

Comment: @CSharpie Well, or actually did you know what this other Q&A talks about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413412/compiler-generated-sealed-class-for-delegate-keyword-contains-virtual-methods

Comment: @CSharpie I've re-updated my answer to drop parts that were unrelated to your question and your updates... At the end of the day, the answer to your Q is ***no***.

Comment: @CSharpie Why? If both compiled delegates are different instances, it seems like there's no caching at all. I would love to demonstrate that there's that caching :D Don't get me wrong. I've put effort on answering you because I wanted to investigate it too. Maybe Eric Lippert checks the answer and can put more light on the topic

Comment: I don't think the fact that there are two delegate instances proves that there's no caching. After all, if you wrap the same method for two different instances in delegates, you'll also get two separate delegate instances.

Answer (score 2):

I'll say that there is no caching anywhere of anything.

[`Expression<TDelegate>.Compile()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs,9d4912c02133de4e,references) calls [`LambdaCompiler.Compile()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,139066f9bd9e7026). From there a new instance of [`LambdaCompiler`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,65b74d122162a33d,references) is created, that initializes the [`_method`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,6d7ce7e4c17f7efc) field (with a `var method = new DynamicMethod(lambda.Name ?? "lambda_method", lambda.ReturnType, parameterTypes, true);`) that will be then used to create first the method and then the delegate. Note that `_method` is readonly, so no one can change it, and is directly used by [`LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,c5ff378c3a5f8142,references) to create the delegate. No caching anywhere.